Why did God allow an angel to fight Jacob if he was already very stressed out? (Genesis 32)
In Genesis 32, Jacob is already anxious about meeting up with Esau (Gen 32:7) and nervous he will kill him and his family. He even came up with this whole plan to soften his brother by giving him gifts and stuff.
Then, on top of all that stress, he fights an angel on that same chapter. Why? It’s such a funny timing. Wasn’t he already stressed enough? It’s like the cherry on the cake.

Shouldn't "allow an angel to" be deleted from the Title question?
¶ Genesis 32:29–30 says "And Jacob asked him, and said, Tell me, I pray thee, thy name. And he said, Wherefore is it that thou dost ask after my name? And he blessed him there.
And Jacob called the name of the place Peniel [facing God]: for I have seen God face to face, and my life is preserved.".
¶ The "man" said Jacob should already know his name (i.e. "THE name"), and Jacob said he had seen God face to face.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

It was Jacob doing the fighting, I believe, stolidly clinging on, requiring a blessing. I think the question needs some clarity regarding the details.

There are two matters here in Gen 32.
"The Man"
First, when Jacob starts wrestling, he simply thinks it was a "man" (ie human) but soon realizes that his opponent is far more than a man. Indeed, Jacob comes to realize that it is God Himself, so he asks for blessing (V26 & V29).

Gen 32:29 - Then the man said, “Your name will no longer be Jacob, but Israel, because you have struggled with God and with men, and you have prevailed.”
Gen 32:30 - So Jacob named the place Peniel, saying, “Indeed, I have seen God face to face, and yet my life was spared.”

WHY??
Jacob was called such because he was "deceiver" - always depending on his own resources to achieve his desired (often selfish) goals.  He obtained his father Isaac's blessing by deception (thus depriving Esau of the blessing); and now he faced an existential crisis - meeting his angry brother Esau whom he thought was bent on revenge.
He decided to use his considerable resources to placate his brother Esau by either buying his favor or bribing him not to kill Jacob and prepared a huge gift of animals.
It was at this greatest moment of fear that God showed up to teach Jacob his greatest lesson - to depend totally on God for all things.  Jacob quickly realized that he wrestled God and sought a divine blessing.  And how did God bless him??
God blessed Jacob by disabling him (wrenching his hip) so that Jacob could not fight but simply had to depend on divine help to survive his meeting with Esau.
The Result?
God worked a divine miracle of grace - Esau's heart was changed - all was forgiven:

Gen 33:4 - Esau, however, ran to him and embraced him, threw his arms
around his neck, and kissed him. And they both wept.


+1 Many thanks for an excellent explanation. And you know as well I that this was not an actual angel. It was the angel of the Lord, the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ/Theophany.

@Mr.Bond - fully agree.  Many thanks.

It began with the words of the Lord to Jacob in Genesis 31:3:

Then the Lord said to Jacob, “Go back to the land of your fathers and to your relatives, and I will be with you.”

Jacob obeyed and returned, knowing he would have to face his brother Esau, whom he had once deceived. This caused him great stress, as he was uncertain of what awaited him. In Genesis 32:1, an angel met him with a camp, reassuring him of the Lord presence.
Despite this reassurance, Jacob was anxious when he heard that Esau was coming to meet him with four hundred men. That night, Jacob sent everyone, including his wives, concubines and sons across the stream, choosing to stay alone on the other side. This solitude reflected his inner turmoil and inability to find peace. During this time, an angel appeared to comfort him.
Hebrew 1:14 states:

Are not all angels ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation?

It is worth noting that Jacob did not want to stop wrestling, suggesting that he initiated the struggle. The angel could have ended it at any time but chose to continue, focusing on relieving Jacob's stress until dawn.
The angel then named him Israel, saying, "because he had struggled with God and with humans and had overcome" (Genesis 32:28). This name not only marked Jacob's personal journey but also symbolized the future struggles and perseverance of the nation of Israel.

A Jewish tradition holds that it was Esau's guardian angel that wrestled with Jacob. It was his job to protect Esau's lands, similar to role of the angelic "princes" of Persia and Greece who protected those lands in Daniel 10:20.
Whether this is case or not, it seems that Jacob had to wrestle internally with with the angel (or God) before he could successfully win Esau's trust. Jacob's conscience must have bothered him because he had not treated Esau fairly. Now, after 20 years of working under Laban, who regularly deceived him in major matters just as Jacob had deceived Esau, Jacob could finally understand Jacob's heart. The final qualification for Jacob to emerge victorious was to wrestle with the angel. On the foundation of thus "seeing God" and receiving the victorious name of Israel, he could also see God in the face of his estranged brother and prevail. Esau, having gained riches himself over the years, overcame his grudge against Jacob and the two brothers embraced.
It was on Jacob's victorious foundation of wrestling with the angel and overcoming his brother's resentment that God worked through Jacob's descendants to send the Messiah to the nation of Israel.
